# Issue with EaselJS

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I developing TD game with EaselJS and faced with one problem.
When enemy come to castle he should should to start attack it with uniq delay.(for example witch:3 seconds, elemental:2 seconds e.t.c.)
How to set this delay with enabled ticker?

```js
        createjs.Ticker.on("tick", moveTick);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(20);
        console.log(mobs);

        function moveTick(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < mobs.length; i++) {
                if (mobs[i].y > stage.canvas.height - castle.castleHeight - mobs[i].elemSize) {
                    setTimeout(console.log("attacking"), 600000);
                } else {
                    mobs[i].y = mobs[i].y + mobs[i].movementSpeed;
                }
            }
            field.update(event);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how many seconds you want to have something wait before performing an action, and you know how many frames per second your program will run at, what you can do is count frames before performing an action.

A good way to count the frames would be to maintain a tick counter, and decrement the counter any time it is a positive number, and then performing an action once the counter hits 0. Here is a code example partially making use of your code of how this might work:

```js
        createjs.Ticker.on("tick", moveTick);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(20);
        console.log(mobs);

        // note that enemy_ticker would probably be a property of your enemy object:
        var enemy_ticker = -1; 

        function moveTick(event) {
            if (event that causes enemy to attack soon) {
                enemy_ticker = 60; // this gives us 3 seconds
            }

            if (enemy_ticker > 0) {
                enemy_ticker--;
            } else if (enemy_ticker = 0) {
                enemy_ticker--;
                // put your code to start your enemy's attack here
            }
            field.update(event);
        }
```